# Filter all item with lowest nearest value in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sorted array is

```
array = [
    { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 },
    { id: 4, orderTotal: 200000 },
]
```

I want find all order total if nearest with a total price.

This is my code

```
const getNearestOrderValue = (arr, totalPrice) => {
    let nearestItem = [];
    let maxSmaller = 0;
    
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (item?.orderTotal <= totalPrice && item?.orderTotal >= maxSmaller) {
          maxSmaller = item?.orderTotal;
          nearestItem.push(item);
        }
    }
    return nearestItem;
}
```

if total price = 80000, my code return correct result is

```
[
   { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
   { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
]
```

but if total price is 120000, my code result is

```
[
  { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
  { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
  { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 }
]
```

I want result is

```
[
 { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 }
]
```

How can i fix this getNearestOrderValue function to response correct? I am looking forward to receive help from anyone.

Comment: You'd need to loop twice - once to find the `maxSmaller` and then to push that item

Comment: why is 50000 nearer to 80000 than 100000?

Comment: @NinaScholz because i want discount for order if total price greater than promotion condition. 100000 don't have enough condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to reset your output array when you find a closer value. There is no need to loop n*2 times and definitely no need to loop n^2 times.

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 },
    { id: 4, orderTotal: 200000 },
];

const getNearestOrderValue = (arr, totalPrice) => {
    let nearestItem = [];
    let maxSmaller = 0;
    
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (item?.orderTotal > totalPrice) {
          break;
        } else if (item?.orderTotal >= maxSmaller) {
          if (item?.orderTotal > maxSmaller) {
            maxSmaller = item?.orderTotal;
            nearestItem = [];
          }
          nearestItem.push(item);
        }
    }
    return nearestItem;
}

console.log(getNearestOrderValue(array, 50000));
console.log(getNearestOrderValue(array, 120000));
```

As noted by Nick Parsons in the comments, you can even break out of the loop once you encounter an `orderTotal` that is greater than the `totalPrice`.

Comment: This is work for me. Thank you for spending time with me.

Comment: You can also do less than `n` loops by returning early once `item?.orderTotal > totalPrice` since the array is sorted.

Comment: @NickParson True enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array and keep only items with smaller total values.

```js
const
    findNearest = (data, total) => data
        .reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
            if (o.orderTotal > total) return r;
            if (r.at(-1)?.orderTotal < o.orderTotal) r = [];
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }, []),
    array = [{ id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 }, { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 }, { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 }, { id: 4, orderTotal: 200000 }];

console.log(findNearest(array, 80000));
console.log(findNearest(array, 120000));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop twice. Once to find the `maxSmaller` item and then to filter the original array:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const getNearestOrderValue = (arr, totalPrice) => {
  let maxSmaller = 0;
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item?.orderTotal <= totalPrice && item?.orderTotal >= maxSmaller) {
      maxSmaller = item?.orderTotal;
    }
  }
  return arr.filter((item) => item?.orderTotal === maxSmaller);
};
console.log(
  getNearestOrderValue(
    [
      { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
      { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
      { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 },
      { id: 4, orderTotal: 200000 },
    ],
    120000
  )
);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is work for me. Thank you very much. Wishing you a great day.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 3, orderTotal: 50000 },
    { id: 2, orderTotal: 100000 },
    { id: 4, orderTotal: 200000 },
];

// Target order total
const targetTotal = 80000;

// Find the item with the order total closest to the target total
const nearestItem = array.reduce((closest, current) => {
    const closestDifference = Math.abs(targetTotal - closest.orderTotal);
    const currentDifference = Math.abs(targetTotal - current.orderTotal);

    return currentDifference < closestDifference ? current : closest;
});

console.log('nearestItem',nearestItem);
```

Check this out it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Won't work for cases where there's multiple orders with the same `orderTotal`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).